# C# Strategy pattern design problem

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I'm having troubles trying to design classes. 
I have abstract `Chip` class, `STM8` class which extends `Chip` and implements `IConfigurable` (which has Configure method).

I expect each class, which implements `IConfigurable` to have a method `Configure`, which takes one arguments to decide what to configure, using strategy pattern (methods).

Psuedo code:

```
public void Configure(Periphial p)
{
  this.periphials[p]();
}
```

Of course things to configure differ on each class. For example, `STM8` can have GPIO and Timers, and `STM8L` can only have GPIO. Then, the way each subclass is created should be stupid-proof so I would like to force people to declare their own `enum` inside their classes.

At last, would it be a good idea to initialize a dictionary with a pair of enum/delegate for showing what is possible to configure? `this.periphials` used in pseudo-code above?

Comment: what does your pseudo code mean? Also I don't see the strategy pattern here.

Comment: What approaches have you tried?  This seems like more of a philosophical question.

Comment: It's a method to invoke certain configurator using periphial enum and then execute its delegate (pointer to a member method within same object). I have more than one question here, sorry.

Comment: @BrokenGlass the second image on your profile is broken. And I have no idea what problem 106 is asking.

Comment: @BrokenGlass, each strategy depends on periphial. Code is missing something that assigns a dictionary with Periphial.GPIO => ConfigureGPIO method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And what if your Periphial (should it be named Peripheral instead?) did have a Configure method?

```
foreach (Peripheral p in peripherals) {
    p.Configure();
}
```

or if your Peripheral returned a configurator?

```
foreach (Peripheral p in peripherals) {
    IConfigurator configurator = p.GetConfigurator();
    configurator.Configure();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try working with generics if you dont have too much peripherials.
So make a type for every peripherial TPeripherial1, TPeripherial2, etc.
Then make a generic interface

```
interface IConfigurable<T> : where T TPeripherialBase
{
     void Configure<T>()
}
```

Then implement as much typed configurable interfaces on you class as it supports.
These all methods can be routed to one private method which will not be type and idiot safe.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do what you suggest with the enum for the possible peripherals.

What I think you should do is check the type of the provided `Peripheral` which is provided to the `Configure()` and return a custom exception of if the type is not supporter.

So for STM8L, you would do:

```
public void Configure(Peripheral p)
{

  if (p is GPIO) ConfigureGPIO()
  else throw new NotAvailablePeripheralException(p);

}
```

If you were able to have some enumeration available for the subclasses of `Chip`, it would be exactly the same as if you could define `Porperties` such as `myChip.GPIO`. Using class inheritage hides what the object `really` is at compile time...